# The system cannot infer the transport information from xxxx url

Tags: ssl, https, proxy, esb, wso2-esb

I have been trying to configure a simple pass through proxy using wso2 esb, which points to a REST service in https port.

I had tried doing the same using my development machine (Windows 7) and it is successful.

But when I try repeating the same in production server, in RHEL, I get `The system cannot infer the transport information` error in system log.

**Things Tried**

1. Created passthrough proxy service pointing to https://some.domain.in/something/something.
2. Tried `CURL` to https://some.domain.in/something/something and its shows the response properly
3. Imported certificate from the site to client-truststore.jks. Same was done locally and it worked.
4. in axis2.xml, edited `<parameter name="HostnameVerifier">AllowAll</parameter>`under https transporter

**Error Message**

1. When clicked in `test` in configuration console, I got the following message, Invalid address

[image: Invalid Address]

2. `CURL` the proxy service URL, and got `Empty response`
3. Checked system logs and saw below logs
   [image: System Logs]

Am I missing out something?

Comment: Have you tried with CURL from your production server or from your windows dev machine ?

Comment: @Jean-Michel  I tried CURL from production and got proper response

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I could see in the wso2-error-logs following messages

```
ERROR {org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.TargetHandler} -  I/O
error: handshake alert:  unrecognized_name
javax.net.ssl.SSLProtocolException: handshake alert:  unrecognized_name
```

Then I realised that I was using **java 1.6** locally but **1.7** in production.
And in **Java 1.7** there are some changes in SSL handling

```
The JDK 7 release supports
the Server Name Indication (SNI) extension in the JSSE client. SNI,
described in RFC 4366 enables TLS clients to connect to virtual
servers.
```

In order to bypass this, I added `JAVA_OPTS="-Djsse.enableSNIExtension=false"` in wso2server.sh and restarted.

This solved my problem. 
Not sure if this is the correct way though

[This url](http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/stratos-dev/201407.mbox/%3CCALv+9EK6PUdBL4cxJkSkNr=FvZcGyKWmtAhjanWNVyc2xvtNwQ@mail.gmail.com%3E) helped me finally